# Error: Could not load the default credentials (Firebase function to firestore)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, firebase-cli

I am attempting to write an onCall function for Firebase Cloud Functions that performs advanced querying tasks on a firestore database (i.e. checking a text query up against AutoML natural lang to get a category, etc) but I keep running into a problem trying to query the database from the function:

```
Error getting documents ::  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.query = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const text = data.text;
    var results = [];
    const promise = db.collection('providers').get()
    promise.then((snapshot) => {
        console.log('marker');
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            results.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});
        });
        console.log('yessir');
        return {results: results};
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents :: ', err)
        console.log('nosir');
        return {results: "no results"};
    });
});
```

Longer output:

```
Function execution started
Function execution took 8ms, finished with status code: 200
Error getting documents :: (etc, same error)
nosir
```

Example 2 (no change in running):

```
Function execution started
Function execution took 1200 ms, finished with status code: 200
marker
yessir
```

I can't figure out where this problem is coming from or how to resolve it.
Any help?

Regards.

Comment: When you initialize the app, did you try getting the default credentials there? Try specifying this in your code `admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});`

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez having the same issue...I tried that, no success

Comment: I just tried that. To no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: Just running `firebase login` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same error "Could not load the default credentials".

The error occured after updating my project dependencies with `npm update`.
More precisely *firebase-admin* and *firebase-functions*.

Before update:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^1.3.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0"
}
```

After update:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^1.3.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
}
```

I added the `serviceAccountKey.json` to my project and changed the imports with the code provided at the service account setting of my firebase project.

From :

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()
```

To:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');    
var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com'
});
```

See [@Fernando Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5666202/fernando-rocha)'s answer below to access the account setting of your firebase project.

Comment: How do you do it in a Typescript project? How do I instruct `tsc` to put the cert in the transpiled folder tree?

Comment: @Sergio I just placed it in the lib folder manually and it worked.

Comment: This answer is extremely bad practice because it involves putting service account keys into the cloud function source. While it will make the keys available to the project, it is inappropriate to put into practice.

Answer (score 73):

What I ***first*** did to solve it was add my firebase admin sdk key to my project.

I downloaded it at

> 

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/**YOUR_PROJECT_ID**/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

[image: Admin SDK Key Download Page]

then at `admin.initializeApp();` I changed to:

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(require('../keys/admin.json'))
});
```

My folder structure is

```
├── key
│   ├── admin.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
```

***HOWEVER***, a better practice and safer approach, as some mentioned already:
You could use environment variables to store your credentials, this way you won't commit it to a repository such as Github, keep it safer from safety breaches and won´t make it hardcoded.

Depending on your project and where you'll deploy it there's a different way to do it.

There are many tutorials around on how to create and access env variables ([like this one](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)), but you could use a name it like the example below:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/admin.json"
```

Comment: @BurnDownTheIgloo did you try this?

Comment: How do you do it in a Typescript project? How do I instruct tsc to put the cert in the transpiled folder tree?

Comment: @Sergio Hi, I used this quick hack to get it working with typescript

1. ```import * as serviceAccount from 'path/to/.json'```

2. ```admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as any)
})```

3. ``` "resolveJsonModule": true```  in tsconfig.json

Comment: In my case the default credentials worked on some machines, and others not, but adding the service account was of course a more stable solution. Great answer and very thorough explanation.

Comment: @Sergio you can see this great tutorial for more details:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer, as it puts a revocable service account credential embedded in the function. Secrets in your source repository is not appropriate, and secrets deployed where a service account credential rotation forces redeployment of your cloud function is also not appropriate.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni You should then propose an appropriate answer

Comment: All of the answers which I upvoted and do not do this terrible security practice are appropriate, it would be inappropriate for me to add an answer.

Comment: This is a tricky problem and I appreciate your answer, most people just want things to work and this apparently got things working for many. However, while this might or might not work for some people, (it did not for me) it could create security issues and is not an optimal solution. There must be a better way. If I find a better solution I will post it.

Comment: @C.Gadd you could also try using it as an environment variable

Answer (score 23):

@aldobaie's answer helped me figure out what was going on for my use case. For those who are not looking to add async/await to all their calls, remember that the firestore calls return promises, so prepending them with `return` has the same effect.

In my case:

```
function doSomething(...) {
    return admin.firestore().collection(...).doc(...).get()
        .then((doc) => {...})
        .catch(err => {...})
}

module.exports = functions.firestore.document('collection/{docId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    return doSomething()
})
```

I think the accepted answer goes against Firebase's recommend configuration. The function environment has access to admin credentials already, and passing your key in the code is not recommended.

I do it like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

Comment: This sorted it for me – returning a promise solved my authentication problem!

Comment: This was my exact same issue as well.  One cloud function started failing when I converted it to async/await, and I had forgot to return the resulting promise.  You can see in the firebase logs that the function returned successfully, and then several seconds later would log the authentication issue.  The async code was trying to execute after the cloud function had terminated, and the auth info was now gone.  Makes total sense.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into the same problem myself. Sometimes the function works and many times it would through the `Error: Could not load the default credentials` error.
The problem I believe have been solved by watching for the Callbacks. You have to keep the function running until the callbacks have been called using the `await` and `async` prefixes.

Firebase Cloud Functions don't allow the access to the processor through callbacks once it's been terminated! That's why we get the `Error: Could not load the default credentials` error.

So, whenever you have a `.then() function` prefix it with `await` and prefix the function it's inside it with `async` and prefix any call to the function with `await`.

```
async function registerUser(..) {
    ...
    await admin.firestore().collection(..)...
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: This worked nicely. For others stumbling onto this issue, there might more than one promise in the function code. Each one needs to be awaited, not only the main one.

Comment: had the same issue, and initially I assumed that my problem is related to this ticket: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/798 but the issue was actually with the promises not awaited properly, as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to [set the service account key in an environmental variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) instead of setting it with a call to `firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({ credential })`.

Linux

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Windows PowerShell

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Postscript: An even better option might be to [use the local emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

Comment: how do you set the Environment variable when deploying to Google Cloud Functions for **Firebase**?

Comment: As far as I recall, we do not need those credentials when we have deployed to Firebase @Sergio.

Comment: Correct. When you deploy to Firebase your functions calls will be from the cloud and thus you are already authenticated. This is because you are not calling the functions locally (as you would if you used *firebase serve* over * firebase deploy*) where you are not logged in and authenticated but from the cloud where you are logged in and authenticated. Thus no authentication errors!

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so I had this error as well and spent a frustrated few days going over multiple sites, articles, videos, etc to try and figure out the cause of this problem so I could get an adequate answer for both myself and everyone else who is struggling.

There are answers to this question in this thread already. However, I tried following most of them to no avail. Some have security issues and others are just  too vague to follow. I decided to post a thorough answer which also addresses the security issues you would have if you followed some of the other answers.

**Alright now that I've gotten that out of the way lets get started!**

First of all your going to need to go to this link - [Getting started with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#cloud-console)

You should see this in the center of your screen -
[image: Getting Started with Authentication]
Next, click on the button I've marked in green. This will bring you to the create service account key page.

You should see a similar screen to the below image -
[image]

- For the *Service Account* option, select new service account.
- Create a name for your service account. This is not important, name it whatever you like.
- For the role option select *Project -> Owner*
- Finally, select JSON option for key type and then hit create.

This should create and download a .json file. Place this file somewhere smart and safe. I created a folder called 'credentials' in the root of my project and placed it in there.

Also I renamed the file to something more readable. While this isn't necessary, following good file/folder naming and structuring practices is important and I would advise you to rename it to something more readable.

*(Its important to note that this file is personal and should not be included in any github repositories/firebase production/etc. This file is for you and you alone!)*

Next open a command prompt window and type in the following command -

set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\Username\Path\To\File\filename.json

This will create an environment variable that is linked securely to your credentials which firebase will recognize and use when you make calls to authenticate yourself.

*(Note - This is the command for windows. If your using mac/linux go to the **'Getting started with Authentication'** page mentioned earlier to get the appropriate command for your operating system)*

There you go, the issue should now be fixed. If anyone has any further questions or problems feel free to comment below and i'll do my very best to help you. I know how frustrating it can be to be stuck with an error like this.

I hope this helps someone at the very least. Happy Programming. 
C.Gadd

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to use @Fernando solution even though there is nothing wrong.

I have prd and non-prd environment. I use firebase use command to push the changes to the correct environment. When I deploy, firebase uses the default service account. Also I do not want to have the keys in the project folder or in my git repo.

The way I solved might not work for others, but want to share here.

The issue came to me when I updated the permission of the firebase project to give a viewer with editor permission. I made that person the owner and rolled back to editor. It went away. It is not justifying as a fix, but worked for me and I do not have to download the key.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. I got the error because I used a different user account to deploy. Redeployed with the default account, and it worked. No need for explicit credential config.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting [serviceAccountKey.json](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) file, you can first set `.env` values from it and then use those:

```js
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";

const adminCredentials = {
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY || ""),
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
};

if (!firebaseAdmin.apps.length) {
  firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(adminCredentials);
}

const firestore = firebaseAdmin.firestore();
```

---

**Old answer**:
This is a known bug in Firebase. see the progress here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1940

However, meantime there are few options to resolve this:

**1 Explicitly passed via code**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://your-app.firebaseio.com"
});
```

**Not recommended** this hard-coding. This json file will not be accessible on server.

**2 Passed via GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**

I'd recommend this way, set environmental variable:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/serviceAccountKey.json
```

For windows: (considering json is at your root path of project.

using powershell:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='serviceAccountKey.json'
```

using NPM script: (notice no space before &&)

```
"serve": "set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=serviceAccountKey.json&& npm run start",
```

(for some reason `cross-env` didn't work)

**3 Available at a well-known filesystem path due to gcloud**
by installing gcloud sdk and running `gcloud auth application-default login`

**4 Available from the Compute Engine metadata API when running on GCP**

Answer (score 2):

One thing it's a bit difficult to find in the docs is the firebase-admin SDK only uses the emulators when *environment variables* tell it to. If you use the service account JSON key as described in some answers here, firebase-admin will talk to prod (on Google Cloud) rather than the emulated version, even if everything else you're doing is on the emulators.

Since most likely you would rather use the emulators for local testing, here's how I set my environment variables in Mac ~/.zshrc:

```
export GCLOUD_PROJECT="your-project-id"
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099
export FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9000
```

The GCLOUD_PROJECT id could be your project id, but apparently any id will work as long as it is a well-formed Firebase project id, so these same environment variables can be used to test all your projects on the Firebase emulators. Try setting these environment variables first for emulator use before you try any of the other solutions.

Another oddity is firebase emulators:start needs these environment variables set, but firebase emulators:exec sets them automagically. When you are in a CI scenario :exec is the better choice, but when actively running tests as you write code having the emulators stay up and running with :start is a faster loop and you'll need the environment variables for it to work properly. By having these in environment variables, your code won't need to change at all when deployed to the Cloud.

Comment: Im in a very similar scenario, where i want to have my emulator up and running with :start so that it doesnt have to boot EVERY TIME i want to run my tests. odly though, as soon as i try to set GCLOUD_PROJECT in .env i just get: `functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load environment variables from .env.`, and as soon as i remove it, or change its name by one character, the emulator boots fine.. but i hit same error as OP. did you hit this issue at any point? also likewise, i dont get any errors when using :exec

Comment: my bad haha. i was using same env file for cloud functions and it reserves those env variables for the context in which it runs. after i set the env variables in test setup file, and removed from actual .env file, and your solution worked. although i dont even think you need to set GCLOUD_PROJECT. just the other ones https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in firebase Error: "Could not get default credentials."

Then go to **firebase console** and go to project setting, where you can find **Service Accounts** option. Click there and you will see the **Generate new private key** under your project setting. 
Copy code for your project language and add it to your project file.

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://your-database-url-that-is-given-under-admin-sdk-snippets"
});
```

After Generating the key you will have option to download. and put it in the project folder. Also set path `var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");`

That's it your are ready.

Comment: This is an repeated answer

Answer (score 1):

None of above.
You may just:

firebase login - It will open browser login

As soon as you do login, returnto console and run:

firebase init - It will run as successfull.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur when the cloud function is not terminated properly.

Whenever you write a cloud function make sure you return promise after the cloud function processing is over, so that cloud function knows that your process is complete.

If you don't return promise then there might be chances where your cloud function might terminate before the processing is complete.

You can refer this to know how to terminate the cloud function. 
[Terminate cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

Answer (score 1):

```js
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

also works.

Answer (score 0):

Download your firebase service account into your project and reference it like this:

```js
<code>
  var admin = require("firebase-admin");
  var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "<database-url>"
  });
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here from a serp trying to figure out why their google cloud function fails with:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more
>   information. at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync

but none of the above helped, you can try to update all(?) of your `@google/whatever` dependencies:
`npm i -E @google/firestore@latest`. Then rebuild, deploy, try again. *It happened to me a few times recently and this worked.*

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. To solve it, just update your node packages by `npm update` inside your project-dir/functions/ directory. Finally, deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS I had to do the following:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myname/serviceAccountKey.json
```

I was getting credential error because the locally running functions emulator could not securely talk to firebase auth running in production.

[Google Cloud Reference](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

- Go on your settings page on Firebase => Service and Account.
- Firebase Setting 1. Parameters 2. Account 3. Download the file and rename it [admin.json]
- Copy the code and paste it

[image]

- Requires 'admin.json' and paste, and run Firebase deploy.

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution for things running in production

Answer (score 0):

For those who still get the same problem event after downloading account key and using it inside your code, make sure it is inside your functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and fixed it with

```
firebase login
```