# Google Cloud Function: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I noticed error in my Cloud Function invocation via Pub/Sub. Every time it throws an Error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
> at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

I already redeployed it with specific credentials for use. And refactored my code accordingly to that proposal [Error: Could not load the default credentials (Firebase function to firestore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127896/error-could-not-load-the-default-credentials-firebase-function-to-firestore/58779000#58779000)

But nothing has been changed. It looks like Google released some updates and it was crashed. I think so because of our mobile app, which does use Firebase SDK and invokes cloud functions directly. But it's wrote on Swift but my Cloud Functions is wrote on JS. So it means that we are using *DIFFERENT* libs, but have *THE SAME ISSUE*. Does somebody know something about that issue?

Comment: FYI, I am encountering the same problem on Cloud Functions that use the Cloud Vision API and that used to work without problem. Apparently this problem occurs for other people as well, see https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/798. Redeploying helps in some cases and in other cases does not solve the problem.

Comment: What SDK version you are using ?

Comment: I faced similar problems yesterday on deploying Cloud Functions. Besides the ok result for this issue in the [status page](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/20001), realize some instability in past hours.